# Strange characters added to the database

Tags: database, migration

So I am migrating over a Wordpress website it has quite a lot of custom fields, long titles and a lot of images.

When I make the migration over the database is not seen and Wordpress goes to a fresh install page, then it makes up a new database. In PhpMyAdmin I can see the old database is still there and it uses normal conventions like wp_commentmeta but the new version (the one WP has no problem seeing but no info from the old site) puts in odd characters like wp_z5v95e_commentmeta?

Even if I kill the database, rename it, re-du the con-fig file, get rid of the plugins, get rid of the theme, do a fresh WP install and I still get wp_z5v95e!

If I have to start from scratch and rebuild the site so be it but it also doesn't see the media library which is key due to the amount of images in the website.

Has anyone seen or know what this is?

Thanks

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't see the media library "?

Comment: Oh, so if I go to the media library in WP admin it doesn't see all the images that are on the server under the uploads folder - dates - images.

Comment: If you can't see images in media library, then you must have used `FTP` to transfer images in `Upload folder`. By transferring with `FTP`  Images won't show in media library Because images won't get their entry in database, on `FTP` upload. Two ways to see images in media, `First`:  Add images manually from media library instead of FTP. `Second`:  Import tables from previous DB to new DB so it got all entries in DB. No entry of image in database, no image in media library as simple as that.

Comment: Maybe you could give some more detail on how you try to do the migration (tools used, steps followed)

Comment: Steps I followed where:

Comment: I ftp transfered the dev site files over to the server 
then I made up a new database 
re did the con-fig file to point at the new database 
then the issues with nothing being seen started 
Also I migrated the site over to a local dev and that worked fine

Comment: If you just make up a new database, obviously you won't find any data in it. The strange characters you see added to your table names are configured in wp-config.php. Look for: `$table_prefix  = 'wp_';`.

Comment: Ah, could having that table_prefix in there have messed up my original database migration? by that I mean if the original database didn't reference that number/table_prefix?

Comment: The variable should be in there, it just has to be the same as before migration, or all tables have to be renamed.

Comment: Hi @JHoffmann, You should post your solution as an answer so that this question/post can be saved from unanswered list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange characters you are referring to are part of the table prefix. This is configured with the variable `$table_prefix` in the file wp-config.php.

```
$table_prefix = 'wp_';
```

When migrating a WordPress installation and setting up a new wp-config.php file you have to make sure, the prefix stays exactly the same as in the former config file. Else all database tables have to be renamed accordingly.